# CSS3 with IE7 issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have tried a few fixes but none work. I am working on the website http://MetroClick.com/

In IE7 the navigation goes bonkers. I tried http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html but it didn't really work out to well as it just stayed the same. Any help will definitely be appreciated as I have been at this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it look acceptable (which is an improvement from completely broken), on `#menu a` replace `float: right` with `display: block`.

This won't make any difference in modern browsers, but will massively help in IE7.

Comment: Thanks, it display's but disables the hover effect on IE and modern browsers.

Comment: Never mind figured out the issue. Had a float:none in the ul area. Works now thanks!